# Java class: limit instance variable to one of several possible values, depending on other instance variables

Tags: java, instance-variables

I am sorry for the vague question. I am not sure what I'm looking for here.

I have a Java class, let's call it `Bar`. In that class is an instance variable, let's call it `foo`. `foo` is a String.

`foo` cannot just have any value. There is a long list of strings, and `foo` must be one of them.

Then, for each of those strings in the list I would like the possibility to set some extra conditions as to whether that specific `foo` can belong in that specific type of `Bar` (depending on other instance variables in that same `Bar`).

What approach should I take here? Obviously, I could put the list of strings in a static class somewhere and upon calling `setFoo(String s)` check whether s is in that list. But that would not allow me to check for extra conditions - or I would need to put all that logic for every value of `foo` in the same method, which would get ugly quickly.

Is the solution to make several hundred classes for every possible value of `foo` and insert in each the respective (often trivial) logic to determine what types of `Bar` it fits? That doesn't sound right either.

What approach should I take here?

Here's a more concrete example, to make it more clear what I am looking for. Say there is a `Furniture` class, with a variable `material`, which can be lots of things, anything from mahogany to plywood. But there is another variable, `upholstery`, and you can make furniture containing cotton of plywood but not oak; satin furniture of oak but not walnut; other types of fabric go well with any material; et cetera.

Comment: `foo` should definitely be an enum

Comment: Is that practical for several hundred possible values? And how about the other logic bits to determine what types of `Bar` it fits?

Comment: Based on the concrete example you have mentioned, it seems to me that `String` is too big of a template for your purpose. You can start defining classes which breaks those several hundred types into smaller categories.That should be a start and you can figure out which types are worth defining a new class and which are just properties which can be assigned upon instantiation.

Comment: Implement some kind of rules engine (e.g. https://github.com/j-easy/easy-rules). Set properties then validate the current object state against your rules.

Comment: AFAIK there's no way around either doing what @jrook says or simply adding such logic to the appropriate setters, sort of how you and jarmod were describing. In either case it's not very elegant. The one thing I'd recommend is if the lists of allowed values/combinations can change from time to time, load it from some external source like a DB or properties file, possibly in an initializer, so you don't have to recompile every time.

Comment: Enum sounds too rigid to me in this case. The list of materials and other validation rules (what can go with what else) could very reasonably change often. I would model these rules separate from the `Furniture` class itself, and run these rules on each `Furniture` instance submitted to the system for adding/updating.

Comment: Could you give a more concrete example of that @jingx? I was thinking the same - that the rules shouldn't be in the setter, but I'm not sure how to approach it. The database solution is good, but a bit of a hassle, and my rules are relatively static, so I'd like to check out other options too.

Comment: @KeizerHarm please accept an answer if it helped you

Comment: @SoroushA I used all of them.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't suggest creating multiple classes/templates for such a big use case. This is very opinion based but I'll take a shot at answering as best as I can.

In such a case where your options can be numerous and you want to keep a maintainable code base, the best solution is to separate the values and the logic. I recommend that you store your `foo` values in a database. At the same time, keep your client code as clean and small as possible. So that it doesn't need to filter through the data to figure out which data is valid. **You want to minimize dependency to data in your code**. Think of it this way: tomorrow you might need to add a new material to your material list. Do you want to modify all your code for that? Or do you want to just add it to your database and everything magically works? Obviously the latter is a better option. Here is an example on how to design such a system. Of course, this can vary based on your use case or variables but it is a good guideline. The basic rule of thumb is: your code should have as little dependency to data as possible.

Let's say you want to create a `Bar` which has to have a certain `foo`. In this case, I would create a database for BARS which contains all the possible `Bar`s. Example:

ID NAME FOO
1  Door 1,4,10

I will also create a database FOOS which contains the details of each `foo`. For example:

ID NAME PROPERTY1 PROPERTY2 ...
1  Oak  Brown     Soft

When you create a Bar:

`Bar door = new Bar(Bar.DOOR);`

in the constructor you would go to the BARS table and query the `foo`s. Then you would query the FOOS table and load all the material and assign them to the field inside your new object.

This way whenever you create a `Bar` the material can be changed and loaded from DB without changing any code. You can add as many types of `Bar` as you can and change material properties as you goo. Your client code however doesn't change much.

You might ask why do we create a database for FOOS and refer to it's ids in the BARS table? This way, you can modify the properties of each `foo` as much as you want. Also you can share `foo`s between `Bar`s and vice versa but you only need to change the db once. cross referencing becomes a breeze. I hope this example explains the idea clearly.

Answer (score 1):

You say:

> Is the solution to make several hundred classes for every possible
>   value of foo and insert in each the respective (often trivial) logic
>   to determine what types of Bar it fits? That doesn't sound right
>   either.

Why not have separate classes for each type of Foo? Unless you need to define new types of Foo without changing the code you can model them as plain Java classes. You can go with enums as well but it does not really give you any advantage since you still need to update the enum when adding a new type of Foo.

In any case here is type safe approach that guarantees compile time checking of your rules:

```
public static interface Material{}

public static interface Upholstery{}

public static class Oak implements Material{}

public static class Plywood implements Material{}

public static class Cotton implements Upholstery{}

public static class Satin implements Upholstery{}


public static class Furniture<M extends Material, U extends Upholstery>{

    private M matrerial = null;
    private U upholstery = null;

    public Furniture(M matrerial, U upholstery){
        this.matrerial = matrerial;
        this.upholstery = upholstery;
    }

    public M getMatrerial() {
        return matrerial;
    }

    public U getUpholstery() {
        return upholstery;
    }  
}


public static Furniture<Plywood, Cotton> cottonFurnitureWithPlywood(Plywood plywood, Cotton cotton){
    return new Furniture<>(plywood, cotton);
}

public static Furniture<Oak, Satin> satinFurnitureWithOak(Oak oak, Satin satin){
    return new Furniture<>(oak, satin);
}
```

Comment: It would work and it would be fast. But having to create an interface for all woods and upholsteries, and a factory method for every valid combination, is a **lot** of tedious boilerplate that must be maintained and recompiled with every change in materials. Plus, any changes to the materials would potentially break existing client code which must be manually fixed--it can't just be recompiled. Additionally, many coding styles frown on marker interfaces.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by changes to material and it breaking the client. My post is an alternative approach if the OP still wants to go static type checked rules. It is up to him/her to decide if it is worthwhile to define all those classes. Just because you need to define 10-20 classes does not mean you have to lose static type checking.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you really want to achieve. Creating objects and passing them around will not magically solve your domain-specific problems.

If you cannot think of any real behavior to add to your objects (except the validation), then it might make more sense to just store your data and read them into memory whenever you want. Even treat rules as data.

Here is an example:

```
public class Furniture {
     String name;
     Material material;
     Upholstery upholstery;

     //getters, setters, other behavior

     public Furniture(String name, Material m, Upholstery u) {
         //Read rule files from memory or disk and do all the checks
         //Do not instantiate if validation does not pass
         this.name = name;
         material = m;
         upholstery = u;
     }
}
```

To specify rules, you will then create three plain text files (e.g. using csv format). File 1 will contain valid values for material, file 2 will contain valid values for upholstery, and file 3 will have a matrix format like the following:

```
upholstery\material  plywood mahogany oak
cotton                  1       0      1
satin                   0       1      0
```

to check if a material *goes* with an upholstery or not, just check the corresponding row and column.

Alternatively, if you have lots of data, you can opt for a database system along with an ORM. Rule tables then can be join tables and come with extra nice features a DBMS may provide (like easy checking for duplicate values). The validation table could look something like:

```
MaterialID UpholsteryID Compatability_Score
plywood    cotton          1
oak        satin           0
```

The advantage of using this approach is that you quickly get a working application and you can decide what to do as you add new behavior to your application. And even if it gets way more complex in the future (new rules, new data types, etc) you can use something like the [repository pattern](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html) to keep your data and business logic decoupled.

**Notes about Enums:**

Although the solution suggested by @Igwe Kalu solves the specific case described in the question, it is not scalable. What if you want to find what *material* goes with a given upholstery (the reverse case)? You will need to create another enum which does not add anything meaningful to the program, or add complex logic to your application.

Comment: I like this answer more than others (because it’s closest to mine :) but I see no benefit to making the loaded data so complex. Plus, it breaks “normalization” (it’s possible for the data to conflict with itself). Also, you’ll need to repeat the logic in the setters so you may as well just move it there.

Comment: @AlvinThompson. The OP can avoid duplication by defining ids (or use primary keys in a DBMS and ORM takes care of the rest). In any case, I noticed that most answers were trying too hard to satisfy the specific example given by the OP while the question seems to be way more general. The point of my answer is *don't complicate your code to only achieve validation.* Of course, if there is a more complex logic there, then more careful designs are warranted.

Comment: Adding IDs just makes the data more complex. Plus, that doesn't address the normalization issue. What I mean by that is you're expressing the same information two different ways. When you do that it's possible to misconfigure the configuration files so one file says, for example, cotton is compatible with plywood while another file says that cotton is **not** compatible with plywood. Believe me, I have heard many, many times people confidently claim "that will never happen--we'll make sure in the code it doesn't", but sooner or later it **always** happens. Then you have a mess to sort out.

Comment: I wish the downvoter would explain the reason for their downvote. I am here to learn too. Thanks!

Comment: @AlvinThompson OF COURSE NOT! I would not have asked the *downvoter* to explain their downvote if I thought it was you!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160031/discussion-between-jrook-and-alvin-thompson).

Comment: Sorry, you're right. It looks like some child downvoted all the answers.

Answer (score 1):

This is a more detailed description of the idea I threw out there in the comment:

Keep `Furniture` a POJO, i.e., just hold the data, no behavior or rules implemented in it.

Implement the rules in separate classes, something along the lines of:

```
interface FurnitureRule {
    void validate(Furniture furniture) throws FurnitureRuleException;
}

class ValidMaterialRule implements FurnitureRule {
    // this you can load in whatever way suitable in your architecture -
    // from enums, DB, an XML file, a JSON file, or inject via Spring, etc.
    private Set<String> validMaterialNames;

    @Overload
    void validate(Furniture furniture) throws FurnitureRuleException {
        if (!validMaterialNames.contains(furniture.getMaterial()))
            throws new FurnitureRuleException("Invalid material " + furniture.getMaterial());
    }
}

class UpholsteryRule implements FurnitureRule {
    // Again however suitable to implement/config this
    private Map<String, Set<String>> validMaterialsPerUpholstery;

    @Overload
    void validate(Furniture furniture) throws FurnitureRuleException {
        Set<String> validMaterialNames = validMaterialsPerUpholstery.get(furniture.getUpholstery();
        if (validMaterialNames != null && !validMaterialNames.contains(furniture.getMaterial()))
            throws new FurnitureRuleException("Invalid material " + furniture.getMaterial() + " for upholstery " + furniture.getUpholstery());
    }
}

// and more complex rules if you need to
```

Then have some service along the lines of `FurnitureManager`. It's the "gatekeeper" for all Furniture creation/updates:

```
class FurnitureManager {
    // configure these via e.g. Spring.
    private List<FurnitureRule> rules;

    public void updateFurniture(Furniture furniture) throws FurnitureRuleException {
        rules.forEach(rule -> rule.validate(furniture))
        // proceed to persist `furniture` in the database or whatever else you do with a valid piece of furniture.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`material` should be of type Enum.

```
public enum Material {
   MAHOGANY,
   TEAK,
   OAK,
   ...

}
```

Furthermore you can have a validator for `Furniture` that contains the logic which types of `Furniture` make sense, and then call that validator in every method that can change the `material` or `upholstery` variable (typically only your setters).

```
public class Furniture {

  private Material material;
  private Upholstery upholstery; //Could also be String depending on your needs of course

  public void setMaterial(Material material) {
     if (FurnitureValidator.isValidCombination(material, this.upholstery)) {
        this.material = material;
     }
  }

  ...

  private static class FurnitureValidator {
     private static boolean isValidCombination(Material material, Upholstery upholstery) {
        switch(material) {
           case MAHOGANY: return upholstery != Upholstery.COTTON;
                break;
           //and so on
        }

     }   
  }
}
```

Comment: The logic in the validator could get much more complex than shown. You'd likely need a nested set of switches.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the approach I'd use (because it involves the least amount of code and it's reasonably fast) is to "flatten" the hierarchical logic into a one-dimensional Set of allowed value combinations. Then when setting one of the fields, validate that the proposed new combination is valid. I'd probably just use a Set of concatenated Strings for simplicity. For the example you give above, something like this:

```
class Furniture {
  private String wood;
  private String upholstery;

  /**
   * Set of all acceptable values, with each combination as a String.
   * Example value: "plywood:cotton"
   */
  private static final Set<String> allowed = new HashSet<>();

  /**
   * Load allowed values in initializer.
   *
   * TODO: load allowed values from DB or config file
   * instead of hard-wiring.
   */
  static {
    allowed.add("plywood:cotton");
    ...
  }

  public void setWood(String wood) {
    if (!allowed.contains(wood + ":" + this.upholstery)) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("bad combination of materials!");
    }
    this.wood = wood;
  }

  public void setUpholstery(String upholstery) {
    if (!allowed.contains(this.wood + ":" + upholstery)) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("bad combination of materials!");
    }
    this.upholstery = upholstery;
  }

  public void setMaterials(String wood, String upholstery) {
    if (!allowed.contains(wood + ":" + upholstery)) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("bad combination of materials!");
    }
    this.wood = wood;
    this.upholstery = upholstery;
  }

  // getters
  ...
}
```

The disadvantage of this approach compared to other answers is that there is no compile-time type checking. For example, if you try to set the wood to `plywoo` instead of `plywood` you won’t know about your error until runtime. In practice this disadvantage is negligible since presumably the options will be chosen by a user through a UI (or through some other means), so you won’t know what they are until runtime anyway. Plus the big advantage is that the code will never have to be changed so long as you’re willing to maintain a list of allowed combinations externally. As someone with 30 years of development experience, take my word for it that this approach is far more maintainable.

With the above code, you'll need to use `setMaterials` before using `setWood` or `setUpholstery`, since the other field will still be `null` and therefore not an allowed combination. You can initialize the class's fields with default materials to avoid this if you want.

Answer (score 0):

We often are oblivious of the power inherent in `enum` types. [The Java™ Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) clearly states *"you should use enum types any time you need to represent a fixed set of constants."*

How do you ***simply*** make the best of `enum` in resolving the challenge you presented? - Here goes:

```
public enum Material {
    MAHOGANY( "satin", "velvet" ),
    PLYWOOD( "leather" ),
    // possibly many other materials and their matching fabrics...
    OAK( "some other fabric - 0" ),
    WALNUT( "some other fabric - 0", "some other fabric - 1" );

    private final String[] listOfSuitingFabrics;

    Material( String... fabrics ) {
        this.listOfSuitingFabrics = fabrics;
    }

    String[] getListOfSuitingFabrics() {
        return Arrays.copyOf( listOfSuitingFabrics );
    }

    public String toString() {
        return name().substring( 0, 1 ) + name().substring( 1 );
    }
}
```

Let's test it:

```
public class TestMaterial {

    for ( Material material : Material.values() ) {
        System.out.println( material.toString() + " go well with " + material.getListOfSuitingFabrics() );
    }
}
```

Comment: The only issue is that changes to materials/fabric would require the code to be recompiled, and then any client code would have to be recompiled.

Comment: Indeed, but the OP had not requested a solution that allows for changing the association between materials and fabrics. Moreover, ***considering practical business requirements as might be applicable in the given context, a fabric that does not go well with a certain wood material would most likely not go well with it in 5 years time***. So I believe this straightforward and uncomplicated solution cleanly solves the problem.

Comment: The issue I’m thinking of is that materials may become available (or not) as prices fluctuate. That’s fairly likely to happen routinely. And never underestimate the power of the guys in suits to muck things up. :)  If a fabric is popular, they may decide to only allow it with “premium” wood to maximize profits. Best to assume that someone will want it changed in the future.

Comment: If you say so :-)

Comment: I should say that the furniture was just an example :) My actual case is a much more specific thing that would take too much time to explain.

Comment: @KeizerHarm In any case my logic still applies. If you can make the code simpler and give yourself the ability to change valid combinations without recompiling, why wouldn’t you?

Comment: @AlvinThompson Yes of course. Just mentioning, since you guys had started talking about furniture prices and whatnot :)

Comment: @KeizerHarm perhaps if none of the answers are adequate for your needs you should amend your question to explain why they’re not?

Comment: @AlvinThompson No, they are all very adequate! I'm just having a hard time figuring out which answer is the best. I'm probably going to take elements from each, tbh.

Comment: Well, who between you two downvoted my answer? ;-)

Meanwhile @KeizerHarm, my motivation is to share with you and others with similar concern. You may build upon the idea or ignore it totally, don't feel pressured. The discussion here benefits everyone and that's the fun.

Comment: Understood, @IgweKalu. And for the record: I upvoted every single answer myself.

Comment: Alright, thanks. Meanwhile, you may want to check this out: [**YAGNI**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it)